# Ionic v4: "Ionic cordova run -l" won't start my app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-cli

**Additional notes for upcoming viewers**
This seems to be a common problem on macOS: https://github.com/ios-control/ios-sim/issues/253

*Temporary solution below this question.*

I've worked on a fresh ionic project a few days ago and I had no problems back then whatsoever.

Today I tried to start the development server: `ionic cordova run -l`  but then I got this error message:

> No target specified for emulator. Deploying to undefined simulator
>
> Device type "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.undefined" could not be found.
>
> An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

Logging currently available devices(`ionic cordova run --list`) gives me this output:

> Available ios devices:
>
> Available ios virtual devices:

It is empty. None devices are available. Not for ios and neither for android.

**Ionic version:** 4.12.0

**Cordova version:** 9.0.0

**Nodejs version:** 11.5.0

I would appreciate any help to make this work again.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your deivce have you enabled usb debuging? what does cmd -`adb devices` say ?

Comment: I've never plugged in my device to develop my app. It always started an emulation via xcode when running ``ionic cordova run ios -lc``

adb devices will return me probably nothing, as no phone is connected

Comment: you have tried this command : `ionic emulate ios --target="iPhone 6 Plus, 8.2"

`

Comment: reference link : `https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/317` , `https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2487`

Comment: I did right now. First, it said that this command had been changed so I started it with ``ionic cordova emulate ios --livereload``. Doing so, I get the exact same error message as in my question above

Comment: >The emulate command has been renamed. To find out more, run:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have upgraded the Mac OS, faced similar problem in past and updating and re-installing iOS-sim was not of much help.

For me following command worked without installing anything further

```
ionic cordova emulate ios --livereload --consolelogs --target="iPhone-6,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2"
```

Also, you can try this one if above don't work

```
ionic cordova emulate ios --livereload --consolelogs --target="iPhone-6,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2" --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
cd platforms/ios/cordova && npm install ios-sim@latest
cd ../../../
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios@4.5.0
ionic cordova emulate ios --target --list
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console
```

That should do it.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer didn't help me. Nevertheless, I really appreciate your help! Thank you.